# How to get fast result while Querying a very large database table?

Tags: sql-server-2005

My client has a very large database. Two tables that contain Patients record are having more than `10 million rows`. When I select Patient record for a particular Patient I get the record in 2-3 seconds. But if I pass `between date` clause in `where` condition , I do not get the records before 25-30 minutes. My query-

```
select convert(varchar(12),[DateTime],101) as [DateTime] , min(cast(Response as int)) as     [MinFallTotal], max(cast(Response as int)) as [MaxFallTotal]
from NurQueryResults
where VisitID = 'W3074332666' and QueryID = 'NURFALLZ'
Group by convert(varchar(12),[DateTime],101)
```

**I get the result of upper query in 2-3 seconds BUT not for this-**

```
select VisitID, min(cast(Response as int)) as [MinFallTotal], max(cast(Response as int)) as [MaxFallTotal]
from NurQueryResults
where QueryID = 'NURFALLZ' and convert(varchar(12),[DateTime],101)='12/23/2010'
Group by convert(varchar(12),[DateTime],101), VisitID
```

**Actual Requirement is-**

```
select TOP 10 AV.VisitID as [UNIT], AV.AccountNumber as [ACCOUNT], AV.Name as [PATIENT NAME], convert(varchar(11),AV.BirthDateTime,101) as [DoB]
, convert(varchar(12),NQ.[DateTime],101) as [DateTime],
(cast(min(cast(NQ.Response as int)) as varchar(5))+ ' - ' + cast(max(cast(NQ.Response     as int)) as varchar(5)) ) as [FALL]
from AdmVisits AV join NurQueryResults NQ ON
AV.VisitID = NQ.VisitID
where   NQ.QueryID = 'NURFALLZ' AND convert(varchar(12),NQ.[DateTime],101) = '12/24/2010'
Group by convert(varchar(12),NQ.[DateTime],101), AV.VisitID, AV.AccountNumber, AV.Name, convert(varchar(11),AV.BirthDateTime,101)
```

**Can anybody tell me why it is taking so time to execute and what is the solution??**

Comment: Most importantly, what indexes are on this table? It sounds like you need one on column holding the datetime that you are trying to use BETWEEN on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to examine the Query Plan for the poorly performing code. Paste your query in a Window and Hit CTRL+L. This should pretty much tell you what it doesn't like.

If you use the SSMS 2008 IDE connected to your SQL2005  databases and run the query plan, i t should also give you a recommendation on any missing indexes that would help your query.

Based on the limited information provided, without seeing  structures, indexes, etc. of the tables involved, your between query should be running in less than a second in most cases..